# cascading drop downs using li and dl with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a series of questions in an FAQ using `<dl>`.  I want to put these into higher level categories using `<ul>` and `<li>` tags that will hide the `<dl>` unless it is clicked, functioning the same way my faq works currently. I am struggling to make this work, as I am incompetent with JavaScript.

https://jsfiddle.net/pberard2002/agdrwjno/

Any help would be appreciated.

I tried to add `<a>` tags to the `<li>` elements and then append the JS to

```
 $('.accordion > li > dt > a').click(function()
```

but that was not a successful move.

Comment: Your talking about `<dl>` but your code shows `dt`?

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: There is a jquery accordion available to you here http://jqueryui.com/accordion/

Comment: @JoshCrozier the question is, how do I add another level to this drop down? I want to maintain the functionality I have using the '<dl>' elements because I have them already live on my page, I was just hoping I could put them inside of an '<ul>' and find a way to get the same functionality.

Comment: @FatherGoose If you update the fiddle with the desired HTML, I'll take a look

Comment: @JoshCrozier  I updated the fiddle HTML and JS to what I feel like they should be, but it doesn't work.  Keeping in mind that I am not terribly familiar with JS.  Any help you could provide would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: @FatherGoose I think you forgot to post the updated link

Comment: @JoshCrozier I'm sorry about that. 

https://jsfiddle.net/pberard2002/agdrwjno/5/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following will work on nested elements.

It starts by hiding all of the elements, then attaches an event listener to all descendant `a` element and toggles the corresponding accordion.

[**Updated Example**](https://jsfiddle.net/670mv8t2/)

```
$allPanels = $('.accordion > .accordion, .accordion > dl > dd').hide();

$('.accordion a').on('click', function(e) {
  var $target = $(e.target).next('.accordion').length ? $(e.target).next('.accordion') : $(e.target).parent().next();

  $allPanels.not($(this).closest('.accordion')).slideUp();
  $target[$target.is(':visible') ? 'slideUp' : 'slideDown']();
  e.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: This works great, Josh. Thank you.  One small issue, when I went to implement the change. Now ever time I click one of the elements, it refreshes the whole page and scrolls to the top. Is there a way to stop that from happening?

Comment: @FatherGoose Updated. You need to add `e.preventDefault()`.

Comment: That's awesome.  Thank you for the help, sir; especially for the explanation.